How to load model by URL using tensorflow-cpu package?
I tried to load a model via URL using tensorflow_hub package with success (the example snippet below):
#using tensorflow_hub
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
model = hub.load(module_url)
print("module %s loaded" % module_url)

And with saved_model too, it works:
#using saved_model file
path = "."
model = tf.saved_model.load(path)

However, I need to read the model via URL using only the tensorflow-cpu package so that my project is as small as possible in terms of package size for heroku slug size limitations.
Is there another way to load model via URL https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4 installing the only package tensorflow-cpu into the project?

Hi ,You want to load models from TF Hub without using tf TF Hub package.There is one more option, you can directly download the model manually using a Python request.Let me know if you are still facing an issue while loading the model.
